# Laravel Eloquent Serialization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, serialization, laravel-5.6

I have a table where the `Primary Key` looks like this: `123456-789` in column `id`.
When I request all the entries from my table using `$allArray = $this->all()->toArray()` I have an issue. All the data arrives as expected but the `id` now looks like this: `123456789`. The `id` column is set as `varchar(24) utf8_general_ci` in the database.

When I `print_r()` my result from `$all = $this->all()` (without `->toArray()`) I can see that the `id` was fetched currently `123456-789`. Then I try to get the `id` again like `echo $all[1]->id` it is `123456789`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should let your model know that primary key is not auto incrementing value else it will try to convert the primary key into an integer.

Simply add this to your model.

```
public $incrementing = false;
```